# Solving Quaternionic Hermitian Matrices using Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Does Eigen allow for spectral decomposition of Quaternionic Matrices? I'm trying to generate matrices from the Gaussian Symplectic Ensemble (Quaternionic Hermitian/Self-Adjoint Matrices) to experiment with the eigenvalue spacings (Wigner Surmise) but after fiddling around for awhile, I'm not sure how to do this.

Do I need to extend the `MatrixBase` class with the quaternion plugin in order to gain quaternionic matrix support, then feed the matrix into `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` afterwards?

I currently have only tried using `Matrix<Quaternion<double>, Dynamic, Dynamic>` and feeding that directly into `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`. This resulted in `clang` spitting out a wall of errors, most of which just seem like missing operator complaints.

Error dump:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/SelfAdjointEigenSolver.h:434:11: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::RealScalar'
      (aka 'Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>') and 'Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>, -1, -1, 0, -1,
      -1> >::RealScalar')
  if(scale==RealScalar(0)) scale = RealScalar(1);

...

/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.1/../../../../include/c++/8.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:224:15: error: invalid operands to
      binary expression ('const Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>' and 'const Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>')
      if (__a < __b)
...

/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/functors/BinaryFunctors.h:361:128: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('const Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>' and 'const Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>')
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE const result_type operator() (const LhsScalar& a, const RhsScalar& b) const { return a / b; }

...

/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/TriangularMatrix.h:769:89: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'int' to
      'Eigen::internal::triangular_dense_assignment_kernel<1, 0, 0,
      Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::TriangularView<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1> >,
      Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>,
      Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0> >, const Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, const
      Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0> >, const
      Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > > >, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>,
      Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0> >, 0>::Scalar' (aka 'Eigen::Quaternion<double, 0>')
         if(Mode==UnitDiag && SetOpposite) m_functor.assignCoeff(m_dst.coeffRef(id,id), Scalar(1));

...

/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/./Tridiagonalization.h:365:31: error: no viable overloaded '='
    matA.col(i).coeffRef(i+1) = 1;

(and then a ton more)
```

I couldn't seem to find anything from searching. My previous linear algebra library of choice (Armadillo) does not have quaternion support from the looks of it.

Comment: Now with by background, I understand what you are getting at, but I don't know the finer points of whether C++ Eigen allows a spectral decomposition to answer your question, but I will add that the target audience that could answer that question off-the-cuff is probably so narrow and small, I wouldn't hold out hope for a quick answer. I hope I'm wrong, but I can count on one hand the number of people I know that retained that knowledge much beyond graduation... IIRC it was a Satellite Attitude Dynamics class where that was most used.

Comment: As of now, this is not supported. First of all that would need a quaternion class which supports more general operations (cf http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=560). But I'm also afraid it would take quite a bit more restructuring inside Eigen's code, e.g., because many algorithms assume commutativity of the matrix entries. Not impossible to solve, but not trivial, either.

Comment: `boost::math::quaternion` would be a better start, but fixing commutativity won't be enough, you'll also have to specialize some parts like Householder reflectors and Givens rotations.

Comment: I'll take a look at boost. I was hoping to use the divide and conquer method since it doesn't rely on Householder transformations from what I can tell, and has a very fast runtime of O(n^2) to find all eigenvalues. The speed is an important requirement since I'm experimenting with rather large matrices.

Comment: I think you only get `O(n²)` after you reduced your matrix to tri-diagonal form (which generally is `O(n³)` _and_ requires Householder reflections)

Comment: Hm...should I try to use the [complex equivalent of GSEs instead](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GaussianSymplecticMatrixDistribution.html)?

My LA knowledge is pretty basic so I'm not completely sure how to generate (2n) x (2n) Hermitians whose transpose (not conjugate transpose) is its inverse in O(n^2).